# Performing action before WCF service is shutdown

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS7. The service has a static class with a static list containing strings (sort of log). It periodically write the entries to a file or db.

However when the IIS decides the recyle the app or terminate for whatever reason, the entries in the static field are lost.

Is there any way I can handle the service shuttingdown kind event and persist the data from memory?

Thanks

Shreedhar

Comment: Handle the [CommunicationObject.OnClosing Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.communicationobject.onclosing.aspx) of the ServiceHost?

Comment: How do I do that? do I derive from ServiceHost? As i said the service is hosted in IIS7 and does not do self hosting.

Comment: You can implement a custom ServiceHost in IIS.  I don't have time right now, but I can give a fuller answer this evening when I get home (I'm on the west coast of the US).

Comment: I would really appreciate your help. But before you do that, will the SelfHosting a service will have same tenets of the service when it was hosted in IIS? For example, I beleive we have a call to System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath to get to the physical path of the file. I am thinking this will only work if service is hosted in IIS. I am sure we can have work around for this particular case but if there are other such differences it would be good know before I switch to a self hosting model.

Comment: The example I'll post (sorry I couldn't do it yesterday evening) will still be IIS-hosted - it will just be using a custom service host derived from ServiceHost - so all the IIS stuff will still be available. I'll post an example in a few hours, sooner if I get a chance.

Answer (score 4):

I've implemented several services via IIS with a custom service host (originally I did this so I could implement IErrorHandler for global error handling).

You'll need two things - an implementation of `ServiceHost` and an implementation of `ServiceHostFactory`, which will call your custom service host.  For example (just the relevant parts of code shown):

```
public class MyCustomServiceHost : ServiceHost
{

    protected override void OnClosing()
    {

        // logic to save off your static data
        base.OnClosing();
    }
}

public class MyCustomServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{

    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {

        return new MyCustomServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
    }
}
```

In your .svc file, you'd have something like this:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="MyCompany.MyServiceName" Factory="MyCompany.MyCustomServiceHostFactory" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="MyCustomServiceHost" %>
```

This is one way to do this (and this dates back to .NET 3.5 days); there are quite likely other ways to accomplish this, but at least this should give you some direction.

Comment: Great, thanks Tim. My app is still in v3.5 of the framework so this would be fine. I will implement and test this solution ASAP.